# Como versionar banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: mysql, git, versionamento, banco-de-dados

No desenvolvimento de um portal web,
utilizando o **git** fizemos o controle de tudo que foi alterado a nível de código no ambiente homologação e com o **jenkins** subimos o site para o ambiente de produção.
Para migrar o banco foi feita um dump de toda a base que foi colocada no outro ambiente.

O problema está nas próximas modificações que interfiram na estrutura, ou no conteúdo do banco de dados.

Com o site sendo utilizado, novos conteúdos vão sendo adicionados e já não posso realizar uma nova cópia do ambiente de homologação sem riscos de perder informações.

Se todas as alterações no banco fossem feitas manualmente eu poderia gerar um arquivo **.sql** e rodar ele no produção quando fosse subir novas alterações.

Mas a instalação de módulos e componentes no site gera alterações no banco que podem não ser tão simples de controlar manualmente.

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de versionar o banco de dados assim como usamos o **git** para versionar o código-fonte.

**UPDATE**

Minha principal necessidade é encontrar uma maneira/método para replicar as alterações feitas no ambiente de desenvolvimento, para o ambiente de homologação e produção.

Comment: Você chegou a avaliar o [Oracle SQL Developer 4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) ? Ele acessa o MySQL e possui recurso de versionamento para GIT. Mas como nunca testei o recurso de versionamento dele, não sei se é limitado apenas para o Oracle e/ou códigos PL/SQL...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Em alguns projetos eu simplesmente salvo *todos* os scripts em arquivos texto num projeto separado e então versiono em minha IDE.

Por outro lado, existem vários frameworks que tentam automatizar a tarefa de "migrar" um banco de dados de uma versão para outra e garantir a consistência.

Um dos que estive estudando é o [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/), embora ainda não tenha conseguido implantar em um projeto.

Comment: É inviável nesse projeto em que estou trabalhando salvar todas as alterações feitas em banco em scripts... mais por conta de alguns parametros de configuração que o CMS salva em banco do que por conta da estrutura do banco. Vou dar uma olhada no link que você passou...

Comment: Com o flyway você salva as "migrações" (alterações no banco) em arquivos individuais numa estrutura de diretórios específica e depois pode gerar um script diferencial entre duas versões automaticamente. Veja: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql.html

Comment: Tem o [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) também.

Comment: nessas ferramentas, eu tenho que realizar as mudanças no banco apenas por meio delas, ou elas monitoram também as alterações feitas diretamente no banco?

Comment: Utilizar esse tipo de ferramentas "obriga" você a fazer as mudanças por meio delas.

Comment: Uma solução é rodar as migrações em um banco de dados staging, e depois aplicar essas mudanças no banco de produção manualmente, com base nas instruções criadas para o banco de staging. Já usei uma ferramenta similar, que rodava as migrações durante o deployment, e posso dizer que é uma das melhores coisas que existem. Montar um banco de dados local para um novo desenvolvedor é um comando, criar um staging novo é um comando, e por aí vai...

Comment: @jtomaszon, nem todas são assim. Como já mencionei, algumas como o flyway possuem interpretadores que permitem você mesmo criar os scripts diferenciais na sua linguagem SQL e depois gerar um script diferencial que pode ser ajustado e enviado para os DBAs executarem, quando for o caso. Entretanto, não sei até que ponto você poderia esbarrar numa limitação de ferramenta com relação aos recursos do seu SGBD.

Comment: Realmente não há nenhuma solução semelhante ao versionamento de arquivos.
Quando o framework dispõe de uma solução própria deve ser uma coisa linda de se , mas no projeto em que estamos trabalhando optamos por documentar (salvar os arquivos .sql) das alterações feitas em banco.


Como não tem nenhum projeto java sendo desenvolvido pela equipe não tive como testar o flywaydb...

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando PHP, recomendo o Doctrine2. Veja: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html

Answer (score 17):

Uma grande dificuldade em se trabalhar com bancos de dados é que as mudanças chegam de dois lados: alterações de dados ocorrendo no ambiente de produção, e alterações de estrutura seguindo o processo "normal" (desenvolvimento, testes, qualidade, produção - ou seja qual for a progressão de ambientes que você/sua empresa use). Ambas têm que ocorrer em harmonia.

### Alterações de Dados

Existe pouca razão para se versionar as alterações de dados, mas se necessário isso pode ser feito simplesmente fazendo um *dump* ou *backup* dos mesmos, e versionando essas cópias da maneira que achar melhor (talvez até o próprio git). É importante, claro, que ao se restaurar essas cópias a estrutura do banco esteja tal qual estava quando a cópia foi feita, mas isso se torna simples quando se mantém no próprio BD um registro das alterações de estrutura (mais sobre isso adiante).

### Alterações de Estrutura

#### Irreversibilidade

Seja qual for o método usado para se alterar a estrutura do BD (execução de um script sql, instalação de componentes externos), essa alteração somente pode ser feita **uma vez**, e não pode ser desfeita. Claro, você pode executar o mesmo script duas vezes e o resultado final ser o mesmo, ou você pode executar um script que traz o BD a um estado idêntico ao anterior, mas ainda assim isso conta como **duas** alterações (principalmente se algo sair errado).

Dada a irreversibilidade das alterações de estrutura, é importante se manter um registro de quais alterações já foram aplicadas a um BD específico, e se uma dada alteração já foi feita, não fazê-la de novo. Uma maneira é manter no próprio BD uma tabela listando quais alterações foram realizadas, e em qual ordem.

#### Testes, testes, testes...

Se uma alteração feita, digamos, no ambiente de desenvolvimento, falhou no ambiente de testes, não se deve simplesmente alterar o ambiente de testes e seguir em frente. Pelo contrário, deve-se restaurar ambos ambientes para o estado anterior à alteração (ainda que isso signifique destruir o BD e restaurá-lo a partir de um backup) e criar uma nova alteração para substituir aquela que não deu certo (descartando-a). Se dessa vez funcionou em testes mas falhou na qualidade, começa tudo de novo...

Isso garante que, uma vez que as alterações estiverem prontas para serem aplicadas ao ambiente de produção, as mesmas já tenham sido testadas múltiplas vezes em diferentes circunstâncias, com diferentes conjuntos de dados pré-existentes.

(e, respondendo diretamente ao seu caso particular, não creio que seja uma boa ideia copiar o estado do ambiente de homologação para a produção - conclusão que você próprio também tirou; o ideal seria aplicar as mesmas ações  - execução de scripts, instalação de componentes - realizadas em um ambiente no ambiente seguinte, na mesma ordem, naturalmente precedido de um backup completo do banco)

#### Migração de Dados

Com frequência os dados precisam ser ajustados em decorrência de uma alteração - colocar valores padrão para uma coluna recém-criada, mover dados e uma tabela pra outra, converter de um formato para outro, etc. Como isso é algo que afeta todos os dados do BD - seja em que estado eles estiverem - e também só é feito uma vez, pode-se tratar esse tipo de alteração como uma mudança de estrutura normal - versionando-a e testando-a de ambiente a ambiente.

Isso pode ser feito em um único script sql ou, dependendo das particularidades de sua ferramenta (o **django-south** por exemplo diferencia entre migração de esquema e migração de dados), em múltiplas etapas. Exemplo:

1. Criar uma nova coluna *nullable*, e marcar uma já existente também como *nullable*;
2. Mover todos os dados da coluna antiga para a nova, convertendo o formato se necessário;

   - Opcional: testar sua camada de aplicação nesse estado;
3. Marcar a coluna nova como não-*nullable*, e destruir a coluna antiga.

### Restaurando a um Estado Anterior

Finalizando, se por qualquer razão for necessário restaurar os dados arquivados no passado, tudo o que você precisa fazer é:

1. Verificar na sua cópia qual era o estado do banco no momento em que ela foi feita (simples, pois o conjunto de alterações que o BD sofreu estavam registradas em uma tabela, e isso foi salvo junto com os demais dados);
2. Verificar se o banco atual está ou não no mesmo estado (i.e. mesmo conjunto de alterações, mesma ordem); se sim, basta restaurar os dados.
3. Se o banco está em um estado **anterior**, basta realizar no mesmo as alterações pendentes até que ele atinja o estado apropriado para restaurar a cópia.
4. Se, por outro lado, ele está num estado **posterior**, então é necessário colocar esses dados em um novo banco provisório, aplicar as alterações necessárias para trazê-lo ao estado desejado, e então transferir os dados pro banco definitivo.

Desnecessário dizer, o código da aplicação a ser utilizado deve estar **numa mesma versão** que dá suporte ao banco em seu estado desejado. Assumindo que você salvou os scripts de alteração no controle de versões, isso consiste em verificar qual a última versão estável que contém aquele conjunto de alterações, e nenhuma mais nova.

> Nota: essa resposta se baseou em parte no artigo (em inglês) ["Database Changes Done Right"](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Database-Changes-Done-Right.aspx) e no modo de funcionamento da ferramenta de migração de esquema [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/), além da minha experiência pessoal.

Comment: Minha principal necessidade, nem chega a ser a possibilidade de retornar o banco há um estado anterior.
Mas sim de poder replicar de maneira pratica as alterações que foram feitas no ambiente de desenvolvimento, para o ambiente de homologação e produção.

Comment: @Guilherme Por mais trabalhoso que seja (sem ferramentas ou scripts que te ajudem no processo), o mais seguro ainda é repetir o mesmo processo em cada ambiente. Usar um processo diferente em um deles - pior ainda, se for o de produção - acarreta no risco de algum problema inesperado e não testado. Se muitas alterações diferentes foram feitas, pode ser vantajoso "condensá-las" em uma só ([perguntei sobre isso](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/157039/44542) no programmers.SE), mas ainda é importante que a mesma seja igualmente aplicada nos ambientes de teste antes de ser posta em produção.

Answer (score 8):

Eu sugiro o uso do Liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org/).

Ele organiza toda a evolução do banco de dados.
Por exemplo.

Quando eu crio uma tabela eu coloco o .sql de criação no liquibase e executo ele. Com isso ele vai rodar o .sql e vai criar métodos de versionamento (criando duas tabelas) no banco de dados.

Agora vamos imaginar que eu preciso fazer um update na tabela e meu banco de dados já está em produção. Vou crio um .sql com o SQL do update e adiciono ao liquibase. O liquibase vai rodar, ele mesmo vai reconhecer que o primeiro script sql (de criação da tabela) já foi rodado e vai rodar o segundo script (update).

Se o Banco de Dados for apagado, ao rodar o liquibase ele vai executar (na ordem configurada) os scripts sql configurados nele.

Acho uma ótima ferramenta, fácil de usar e pode ser usada em produção sem nenhum problema.

Answer (score 5):

O ideal é configurar seu servidor para gerar um DUMP do banco assim como de seus dados em um arquivo de texto, e realizar o versionamento por meio deste.

Versionamento do Banco de dados montado em si não é possível.

E outra, o banco de dados está sempre mudando certo? Então no seu caso deve ser um versionamento somente da estrutura do banco certo? Para gerar um dump sem os dados deve-se fazer assim:

```sql
mysqldump -h host -u user --no-data --database nomedobanco > arquivo.sql -psenha
```

Comment: Eu não esperava encontrar uma forma de versionar o banco em si realmente...
Está sendo bem complexo encontrar uma forma ideal de fazer isso.
Por que na banco de homologação há mudanças na estrutura, mudança de parâmetros de configuração que ficam salvos no banco.
E nem sempre é fácil extrair o script sql que é executado no processo de instalação de um componente.
Além disso constantemente há adição de novo conteúdo diretamente no banco de produção.

Comment: Será que funcionaria eu gerar um DUMP das duas bases e mescla-los usando o próprio git?

Comment: Funcionaria sim. No caso ai o ideal é otimizar o processo de desenvolvimento para não executar scripts somente no banco de produção, ou de alguma forma salva-los separadamente. Ou até mesmo manter um terceiro banco que seria o modelo para os outros onde tudo seria executado nele também para garantir a integridade

Comment: Vou ter que ver com o pessoal de infra como fazer...

Answer (score 4):

Sua pergunta deixa em aberto duas situações:

1. Versionar a estrutura de dados do seu sistema durante o processo de desenvolvimento.
2. E rotina de backups dos dados armazenados pelo seu sistema.

Para a situação 1 é so vc versionar o DUMP da estrutura de dados utilziada naquela versão  do sistema, tal como você faz com os fontes do sistema.

Para a situação 2, você pŕecisa definir uma rotina de backup dos dados, que vão além da estrtura, ai existem várias técnicas, seja um script para fazer o dump dos dados, técnica de replicação e até servidores de backups (2 instancias de banco em servidores diferentes).

São dois momentos totalmente distintos e que merecem soluções distintas, uma coisa é versionar e outra coisa é ter a cópia de segurança.E pela explanação da sua pergunta, você precisa definir uma rotina de backup/recovery para seus dados e isso não deveria ser versionado junto com o código do seu sistema e sim em outra estrutura de versionamento se deseja usar essa técnica.

Comment: Até conseguimos sobreviver ao processo de desenvolvimento sem o uso de nenhuma técnica para versionar o banco. E como essa etapa já passou(para esse projeto) o mais urgente pra mim é encontrar uma solução para a segunda etapa...

Comment: @Guilherme então creio o que você precise seja uma rotina tipo essa aqui que eu uso nos meus servidores:

https://gist.github.com/mingomax/7930129

Creio que irá te ajudar nisso.

Comment: Geralmente uso alguma ferramenta pra complementar o DUMP, um banco meio bugado pode resultar em um DUMP bugado, existem ferramentas de backup mais poderosas, como o xtrabackup ( http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/ ) da percona.

Comment: @Mingomax experimente usar --opt no seu script de DUMP

Answer (score 4):

Eu recomendo uma outra abordagem.

Após você fazer um backup full, pode recolher as diferenças nos **binlogs**
O jeito de fazer *incremental backups* do teu MySQL Server

Recomendo leitura (em inglês)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog-backup.html

Answer (score 4):

Eu estou utilizando **MySQL Workbench** e **Laravel 4**.

Para cada mudança no banco de dados, fico com cinco arquivos novos no diretório padrão `app/database/migrations` do Laravel.

Tudo começa usando a linha de comando:

`php artisan migration:make tabela_faturas`

Isto faz com o que o Laravel crie um script PHP em `app/database/migrations`, que recebe um nome padronizado, contendo data e hora.

Em seguida, eu copio o arquivo do MySQL Workbench mais recente (extensão "mwb") e coloco o mesmo nome que o arquivo PHP gerado automaticamente (só a extensão fica diferente). Aplico as alterações no esquema, e com a ferramenta de sincronização, gero o arquivo SQL que aplica as mudanças no esquema. Salvo de novo com o mesmo nome, só que com a extensão "sql". E, para completar, gero uma imagem "png" do diagrama, e dou o mesmo nome.

Por último, reabro o arquivo "mwb" anterior, e novamente usando a ferramenta de sincronização, gero o SQL que reverte as alterações, e salvo com o sufixo "_revert".

Ou seja, para cada nova versão do banco de dados eu fico com CINCO arquivos novos, no diretório `app/database/migrations`. Eis um exemplo real:

```
jbruni@jbruni-laptop:~/pdm/dev/app/database/migrations$ ls -1

2013_09_29_045622_create_schema.mwb
2013_09_29_045622_create_schema.php
2013_09_29_045622_create_schema.png
2013_09_29_045622_create_schema_revert.sql
2013_09_29_045622_create_schema.sql

2013_10_08_015925_create_extra_table.mwb
2013_10_08_015925_create_extra_table.php
2013_10_08_015925_create_extra_table.png
2013_10_08_015925_create_extra_table_revert.sql
2013_10_08_015925_create_extra_table.sql

2013_10_21_185836_faturas_and_other_upgrades.mwb
2013_10_21_185836_faturas_and_other_upgrades.php
2013_10_21_185836_faturas_and_other_upgrades.png
2013_10_21_185836_faturas_and_other_upgrades_revert.sql
2013_10_21_185836_faturas_and_other_upgrades.sql

2013_10_30_095146_enhanced_business_model.mwb
2013_10_30_095146_enhanced_business_model.php
2013_10_30_095146_enhanced_business_model.png
2013_10_30_095146_enhanced_business_model_revert.sql
2013_10_30_095146_enhanced_business_model.sql
```

Por fim, o conteúdo dos arquivos PHP é sempre o mesmo. Eu só preciso tomar o cuidado de **MANTER o nome da classe** que o Laravel também gera automaticamente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class EnhancedBusinessModel extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $vals = Config::get('database.connections.mysql');
        $script_path = str_replace('php', 'sql', __FILE__);
        $command = "mysql -u{$vals['username']} -p{$vals['password']} -h {$vals['host']} -D {$vals['database']} < {$script_path}";
        shell_exec($command);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $vals = Config::get('database.connections.mysql');
        $script_path = str_replace('.php', '_revert.sql', __FILE__);
        $command = "mysql -u{$vals['username']} -p{$vals['password']} -h {$vals['host']} -D {$vals['database']} < {$script_path}";
        shell_exec($command);
    }

}
```

Isso deixa tudo bem documentado, organizado, e dentro da habilidade de ir para frente e para trás através das "migrations" do Laravel.

Os arquivos entram num *commit* do repositório Git do projeto, naturalmente...

---

Além disso, sempre faço o seguinte também:

1. Deixo um cron job diário para fazer back up do banco de dados (via mysqldump para um servidor diferente)
2. Deixo o *binary log* ativado, caso seja necessário restaurar o banco de dados para um momento exato no tempo. (Já tive que fazer isso uma vez, e graças ao binary log + daily backup, foi um sucesso.)

Comment: O projeto em que eu estava trabalhando na época que precisei dessa solução foi finalizado. Mas achei interessante o seu processo, vou tentar aplicar parte dele em algum projeto futuro.