# Boas práticas para criar e versionar procedures

Tags: sql, versionamento

- Qual a melhor forma de criar, alterar e versionar procedures?

Onde trabalho nós fazemos da seguinte fluxo:

- Verificamos se a procedure existe caso sim excluímos ela e então criamos novamente.

Para ***versionar*** eu utilizo um cabeçalho similar a esse:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nome Procedure: SP_NOME_PROCEDURE
Projeto.......: Nome Projeto
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Autor                           Data                            Descrição
-----------------------------   ----------                      ----------------
Desenvolvedor 1                 01/01/2014                      Criação
Desenvolvedor 2                 01/02/2014                      Alteração
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Eu costumo guardar o código das procedures no meu sistema de controle de versão, e o controle é feito por lá.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Em minha experiência, a melhor forma garantir a devida atualização de um sistema como um todo é versionado todos os artefatos, incluindo aqueles do banco de dados, em um sistema de gerenciamento de versões (SCM), e garantindo que todas atualizações serão aplicadas.

## Más práticas

Falando especificamente do banco de dados, já vi várias equipes que usavam um banco de dados em desenvolvimento como modelo e então exportavam as alterações para produção. Isso sempre resultou em muitos problemas, tais como: alguém pode apagar o banco de dados sem querer, alguém pode realizar alterações sem que os outros percebam, alguém pode sobrescrever por engano alguma procedure e ninguém vai perceber e assim por diante.

Outra abordagem que considero falha é os desenvolvedores criarem um script específico para cada versão do sistema. Por exemplo, eles compartilham uma pasta na rede e a cada alteração alguém vai lá e acrescenta o que fez. O problema é que alguém sempre esquece de alguma coisa. E sempre acontece de alguém querer atualizar N versões de uma base, forçando os desenvolvedores a criarem um script personalizado juntado as alterações dessas `N` versões.

## Boas práticas

### Versionamento em um sistema de gerenciamento de versões (SCM)

Por isso, tenho como melhor prática ter **todos** os elementos do banco de dados (tipos definidos pelo usuário, tabelas, alterações em tabelas, views, procedures, triggers e carga de dados) cada um em seu próprio arquivo `.sql` em uma pasta versionada no SCM.

Os artefatos de bancos de dados recebem sempre a mesma *tag* do código-fonte para manter tudo do sistema "casado".

### Idempotência

Se ocorrer um erro no meio de um script a estrutura da base de dados pode ser atualizada parcialmente. Então você terá que verificar individualmente quais atualizações foram ou não aplicadas e montar um novo script baseando-se nisso. É um trabalho grande.

Mas se cada alteração verificar se já foi anteriormente aplicada ela não causar erros se for executada novamente.

Então, cada arquivo `.sql` individual deve verificar de alguma forma se já foi executado antes de tentar aplicar alterações. Por exemplo, uma adição de coluna verifica se a coluna já existe.

No caso de procedures, triggers e views, elas podem ser sempre recriadas, exatamente como citado na pergunta.

### Concatenação num script único

Pode-se ainda usar uma ferramenta qualquer para concatenar os diversos arquivos em um ou mais arquivos grandes a serem executados no ambiente de destino.

Como cada arquivo é idempotente, juntar todos em um único garante que a versão do sistema sempre será a mais atual, mesmo que o script seja executado numa base muito desatualizada.

Em um projeto que trabalhei, onde tínhamos todos os artefatos do banco de dados versionados e idempotentes, montamos um script que era capaz tanto de atualizar a base de uma versão para outra quanto de criar a base de dados completa do zero.

Existem algumas ferramentas que já se propõe a fazer isso por você, como citei [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188/227).

### Controle de versão no arquivo

Também uso um cabeçalho em cada script, cuja versão é vinculada com o CMS. Assim é possível rastrear em cada ambiente qual é a versão da procedure que deveria estar na base de dados de acordo com a versão do sistema.

Um caso interessante em que já trabalhei era um sistema que tinha versões específicas de procedures para Oracle e SQL Server. Como tinha as versões no cabeçalho, acrescentei no script de *build* do sistema uma validação para impedir o *build* caso a versão do cabeçalho de uma procedure PL/SQL estivesse diferente da versão equivalente em T-SQL.

Enfim, dessa forma pode-se verificar a consistência de uma instalação do sistema a qualquer momento.

## Ferramentas Específicas

A abordagem apresentada acima é agnóstica ao SGBDR que você está utilizando.

No entanto, se você trabalho com uma tecnologia específica, consulte as ferramentas de controle de versão específicas.

Por exemplo, o SQL Developer da Oracle faz integração com o SCM e permite gerenciar os scripts pela IDE.

A Microsoft disponibiliza o SQL Server Data Tools para o controle dos artefatos de banco de dados em arquivos `.sql`. [veja um artigo em Inglês sobre isso](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/auto-deploy-and-version-your-sql-server-database-with-ssdt/).

O [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/workbench_database_management.html) possui um editor visual de banco de dados que faz sincronização com o servidor ou permite a geração de scripts a partir do modelo.

## Considerações finais

Todos os conceitos apresentados devem ser usados de acordo com o projeto.

A exigência de controle varia muito se você tem um ou muitos clientes, se possui acesso direto ao banco de produção ou possui intermediação e análise de DBA's, etc.

Analise todas as técnicas e abordagens e escolha a que melhor se enquadrar para o seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

ou salva a .sql em uma pasta própria para isso ou edita a antiga como

```
stp_nome_procedure_bkp01
stp_nome_procedure_bkp02
stp_nome_procedure_bkp03
```

deixando no próprio database, já fui muito salvo porque eu tinha o código antigo da stp
depois de x em X tempo faço uma limpa...

Eu costumo utilizar um cabeçalho parecido ao seu e deixo um backup da storedprocedure no proprio database...algumas exceções salvo em uma pasta própria.

*Uma sugestão off topic é não utilizar `sp_` como prefixo de stored procedure, prefira `stp_`  pq `sp_` são stored procedure de sistemas...então o sistema verifica primeiro lá depois na suas..perde um pouco de desempenho*