# É possível incluir o versionamento do banco de dados no commit (GIT)?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, git, versionamento

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o versionamento do banco de dados (no meu caso MySQL) através do GIT, ou se existe alguma outra forma eficaz para se fazer.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183/como-versionar-banco-de-dados-mysql/187

Comment: Porque você não faz um export da estrutura para um .sql e faz o controle desse .sql? É só um dica de como fazer isso de forma muito simples.

Comment: Muito boa a dia, obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, dependendo das tecnologias envolvidas.

As bases de dados em si, geralmente não disponibilizam meios de versionamento. No entanto, algumas frameworks criam meios de aplicar *patches* a uma base de dados, e de a modificar incrementalmente. Estes *patches*, ou *database migrations*, podem ser versionados.

O exemplo mais conhecido é o [Active Record](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) do Ruby on Rails.
Eis um exemplo de como alterar o tipo de uma coluna de uma tabela:

```
class ChangeProductsPrice < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      change_table :products do |t|
        dir.up   { t.change :price, :string }
        dir.down { t.change :price, :integer }  # rollback
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Em C#, por exemplo, também podemos usar as [*database migrations* da Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

```
public partial class AddPostAbstract : DbMigration 
{ 
    public override void Up() 
    { 
        AddColumn("dbo.Posts", "Abstract", c => c.String()); 
        Sql("UPDATE dbo.Posts SET Abstract = LEFT(Content, 100) WHERE Abstract IS NULL"); 
    } 

    public override void Down() 
    { 
        DropColumn("dbo.Posts", "Abstract"); 
    } 
}
```