# Versionamento de Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysql, git, sourcetree

Utilizo `Git` + `SourceTree` para o versionamento e compartilhamento do projeto com os outros membros da esquipe.

Porém estamos com alguns problemas relacionados ao Banco de Dados.
É possível realizar o compartilhamento do mesmo? Como por exemplo dar commit no BD e depois um pull pelo outro usuário ?

Comment: [Como versionar banco de dados mySQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183/910)

Comment: Uma maneira simples de fazer isso, é você colocar uma pasta MISC, com os arquivos SQL de inserção, alteração de banco, etc... dentro do seu projeto.

Answer (score -1):

O versionamento do banco têm sua própria ferramenta: chama-se "migration".

Praticamente todos os frameworks PHP têm seu próprio recurso de migration.

Mas já trabalhei em projetos que simplesmente NÃO tinham frameworks... (pasmem). Nesse caso eu criei uma pasta chamada "migrations" dentro do projeto e nessa pasta eu instanciei um sub-projeto do Laravel. Não usei o Laravel para absolutamente nada além de gerar as migrations para o banco. Sim, é uma gambiarra, mas acabou com o problema de versionamento de banco entre desenvolvedores:

Se interessar, segue link:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

Desenvolver um projeto sem framework e sem migrations... Bom, funciona se vc trabalha sozinho... Mas basta colocar 2 desenvolvedores trabalhando juntos que vira um inferno...