# ferramenta ou tecnologia para auxiliar no controle dos dados do banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, git, versionamento

Eu tenho uma aplicação Web, que constantemente o banco de dados recebe dados, a aplicação esta toda atrelada ao banco.

se uma alteração for feita pode comprometer todo o sistema, queria poder voltar um ponto quando necessário.

O GIT serve para controle de versão de arquivos.

teria alguma ferramenta ou tecnologia para auxiliar no controle dos dados do banco de dados ?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como versionar banco de dados mySQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183/91)

Comment: algo assim, mas não versionamento do mysql, mas do estado dos dados .

Comment: Entendi, achei que era o versionamento da estrutura e não dos dados

Comment: Você está falando de *back up*. Isso pra mim é *back up*. Você faz ***back up*** dos dados ou usa uma *seed* para testes. No mais, novamente, *back up*.

Comment: eu sei que existe back up, quero saber se não existe algo mais pratico para fazer o controle dos dados

Comment: Talvez algo que passe mais perto seja a funcionalidade [flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#i1009447) do Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir da  versão 9i do banco de dados da Oracle, foi introduzido um conceito chamado undo, no qual permite você recuperar dados excluídos ou alterados durante um período de tempo. Exemplo select * from clientes as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '10' minute. Não sei se existe para mysql, teria que pesquisar.
Neste link está bem explicado esse conceito.
http://laercioleo.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/oracle-comando-milagroso-como-recuperar.html

Comment: eu cheguei a encontrar algo como COMMIT e ROLLBACK mas não entendi se serve ainda

Comment: COMMIT e ROLLBACK, são comandos utilizados dentro de uma transação. Exemplo você fez uma procedure que executou várias atualizações/exclusões/inclusões e na hora que você commitou ocorreu algum erro caso você chame o ROLLBACK, todas as ações realizadas dentro dessa transação serão desfeitas. 
O conceito UNDO da oracle funciona como se fosse um versionamento das tabelas, mas por um determinado período de tempo.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma solução automática para isso, você tem que criar o mecanismo de versionamento manualmente.

você pode por exemplo inserir um campo chamado VERSAO na tabela e não permitir update nos registros, para atualizar um registro você cria um novo com o número da versão incrementado. Logicamente isso irá inflar sua tabela, por isso você deve ser criterioso ao definir quais tabelas do seu sistema você vai querer manter esse histórico de revisões.

Outra opção é criar uma outra tabela somente para manter as versões antigas do registro, por exemplo você pode ter uma tabela CLIENTES e uma tabela CLIENTES_HISTORY, que possua os mesmos campos, mais um número de versão, data da revisão, usuário que fez a alteração, etc. Esse processo pode ser feito via triggers para facilitar.
Ao "editar" um registro você deve inserir o registro atual na tabela de revisões. Ao deletar um registro você pode fazer uma deleção física em cascata ( apagar nas duas tabelas) ou fazer uma deleção lógica (marcar o registro como desativado).

Tudo isso é trabalhoso, mas se seu sistema precisa de histórico dos registros por motivos de auditoria, essas são algumas opções. Recomendo a segunda.

[Este tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323065/how-to-version-control-a-record-in-a-database) possui mais discussões sobre o assunto.

Comment: o problema é que as alterações não são feitas por um script que eu rodo, um usuário esta usando a aplicação e que pode fazer estas alterações, eu não tenho o controle do que foi mudado e quando.