# Como alinha a versão do banco de dados com a aplicação PHP?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, engenharia-de-software, versionamento

Trabalho em um projeto que as versões do sistema são incrementadas manualmente no [modelo semântico](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/), geralmente após um [sprint](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_(desenvolvimento_de_software)) uma nova versão é lançada quando um trabalho é mesclado à ramificação principal e passa nas rotinas de [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). E eu só tenho programadores Javascript e PHP disponíveis para esse projeto e o banco de dados usado é o MySQL.

A cada ciclo de desenvolvimento pode ter gerado alterações no banco ou não alterações que podem ser estruturais(tabelas,clunas), lógicas (functions, triggers, procedures) ou de dados (registros em tabelas).

Alinhas as releases do software com o banco de dados tem se mostrado um verdadeiro desafio pois cada cliente representa uma base dados e deve ser atualizada de forma individual e o controle da versão do banco de dados é feito através de um script de diferenciação da estrutura do banco de dados junto com os comandos de INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE dos registros, conforme sugerido nessa pergunta: [Como versionar banco de dados mySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183/7130).

A principal desvantagem dessas técnica é que é possível apenas avançar a versão, o rollback não é possível seria interessante "retornar" ou "avançar" entre as versões, com possibilidade de um rollback caso a versão apresente uma instabilidade em um determinado cliente.

O comportamento esperado era autonomia da aplicação de ao atualizar ou regredir a versão fosse aplicado as alterações necessárias no banco. Por exemplo, um campo foi adicionado ou uma trigger alterada, a própria aplicação já aplicasse essa alteração de acordo com a atualização.

Em um projeto aonde apenas programadores php estivesse disponíveis, e que o banco de dados seja o mysql, qual o framework, ferramenta ou metodologia  disponível no mercado para criar um versionamento do banco de dados juntamente com a aplicação?

Comment: Chegou a ver [Como versionar banco de dados mySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183/91) ?

Comment: Sim, antes dessa ferramenta automática usávamos a técnica da resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188/7130, porém se tornou mais custosa do o modelo que usa um software para comparar estrutura  que mencionei na pergunta. Obrigado por lembrar, irei citá-la na pergunta.

Comment: O que é muito comum encontrar é um "Migrador" mas não são de fato gerenciadores de versão, já que você não consegue realizar um rollback na migração.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada no http://www.liquibase.org/ é uma melhoria do Migrations

Comment: Dá uma olhada em como usar o Eloquent sem Laravel para projetos proprios https://siipo.la/blog/how-to-use-eloquent-orm-migrations-outside-laravel (ps: não testei)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Se hoje você fosse iniciar um projeto com esses cenários previsíveis, tendo apenas programadores php disponíveis para você,  qual seria o framework/ferramenta/metodologia a utilizar para contornar esse problema?

Comment: Para ser sincero não sei dizer, no entanto atualmente eu trabalho com banco isoladamente do PHP, eu sempre tento trabalhar de maneira mais simples, geralmente modelo o banco em ferramentas como workbench. Mas cada projeto e pessoa tem uma maneira de trabalhar, as vezes o que é bom pra mim não será bom pra ti.

Comment: Leo, uma sugestão bem boba, seria talvez salvar o esquema junto no teu servidor GIT, não sei ao certo, depende muito do projeto.

Comment: Show, me deu algumas idéias aqui! Eu dificilmente conseguirei implimentar algo assim no projeto atual, mas gostaria de elaborar uma abordagem melhor para os próximos projetos.